# How to change opacity of a region in an RGB image (numpy, cv2)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a RGB image which as a given shape like `(200, 200, 3)` as an `np.array` with values between 0 and 255.

I also have a boolean `np.array` of shape `(200, 200)`, which I'll call mask.

What I want is to reduce the opacity of the image in the mask while leaving the rest unchanged, by a given amount.

I know I can convert the RGB image to RGBA with `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)`

Edit:
So I could fix the problem of changing the image at the mask but then I get a RGBA image, but I need it to be RGB. By using `cv2.cvtColor(img_rgba, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)` it just looses the A channel and I get back the original image. Any ideas on how to convert RGBA to RGB without losing the A channel?

Comment: I think you'll have to convert from RGB to RGBA, change the opacity and then back to RGB.

Comment: That was my idea, but as I said in the edit if I do that I simply lose the A channel.

Comment: Multiply the mask (in range 0 to 1) by your RGB image. Talking about opacity/transparenecy makes no sense on an RGB image. It only makes sense when you have an RGBA image.

Comment: Why do you need the channel once you have the image you need?

Comment: Got it so that was probably the problem. I wanted to simulate opacity in an RGB image.